# Where to find intelliJ Visual Studio keymap reference card

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping

There is a default key map card for intelliJ that you can find here [default key map card](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) however I can't find the same card for Visual Studio key mapping (see screeshot below) or any other key mapping card for that matter.

Where to find key mapping card for other types of bindings except default? please see screenshot below

[image]

Comment: http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/ why should idea provide a key binding chart for visual studio?

Comment: added screenshot

Answer (score 2):

A very good keymap reference description is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx).

It also works in products from JetBrains.

Answer (score 1):

Because it´s from JetBrains and you target Visual Studio maybe you are looking for the Visual Studio Resharper KeyMaps: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper_DefaultKeymap_IDEAscheme.pdf
https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper_DefaultKeymap_VSscheme.pdf